# HasManyThrough with another relationship in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 models:

Tournament, Category, Team

A Tournament hasMany Category

A Category hasMany Team

Tables:

```
Tournament: Only attributes
Category: id, tournament_id, name
Teams: id, category_id, name
```

I would like to get all teams from a tournament by: $tournament->teams

I tried :

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Team::class,CategoryTournament::class);
}
```

Then I need an extra relation of my team: team->category->name;

but the result of this HasManyThrough has no relationship....

Any Idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Category` model :

```
public function team ()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Teams');
}
```

In `Teams` model :

```
public function category ()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Category', 'category_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think should be like this, Try.

According to laravel documentation :

```
countries
    id - integer
    name - string

users
    id - integer
    country_id - integer
    name - string

posts
    id - integer
    user_id - integer
    title - string
```

With this you can add relationship :

```
public function posts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Post', 'App\User', 'country_id', 'user_id');
    }
```